# Can't pass environment variables to an sbt task in intellij

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework, sbt

When running a play application from IntelliJ, VM parameters and environment variables greyed out in run configuration when 'Use sbt shell' checked.
How can I pass an env variable to the sbt task, other then unchecking the 'run as sbt task' checkbox or setting the env variable globally on the machine?

[image]

Comment: Use `.sbtopts`?

Comment: Thanks @CrazyCoder
Would you convert this to an answer so that I could accept it?

Comment: I can see how `.sbtopts` can be used to pass the actual VM parameters, but didn't find how to use it for the environment variables. If it worked for you, please feel free to write the answer yourself and describe what you did.

Comment: Using `-DPARAM=VALUE` in `.sbtopts` worked for me

Comment: It may work for your specific app, but normally the environment and Java properties are accessed using the different API methods. It doesn't look like `System.getenv("PARAM");` will work. Could you please double check?

Answer (score 1):

Been there. Use .env file and add plugin: https://github.com/mefellows/sbt-dotenv to your project. Working for me great.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just needed to disable using the SBT Shell and it would've allowed you to set ENV_VARS. Not exactly sure why is that.

Comment: please give a proper explanation with the code of your question. if required.

Comment: It's really just a click on `Use sbt shell`. It's in the prinscreen.